# How to define a global variable in JavaScript that can be accessed in all the functions

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Here's a sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult() {
alert(document.myForm.myInput.value);
}
function getFocus() {
  if (document.myForm.myInput.value == document.myForm.myInput.defaultValue) {
    document.myForm.myInput.value = "";
  }
}
function loseFocus() {
  if (document.myForm.myInput.value == "") {
    document.myForm.myInput.value = document.myForm.myInput.defaultValue;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
        <input name="myInput" value="Hello world!" onfocus="getFocus();" onblur="loseFocus();"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="displayResult();" value="Display input value">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works with no problem, but the following doesn't although the variable *x* seems right:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.myForm.myInput;
function displayResult() {
alert(x.value);
}
function getFocus() {
  if (x.value == x.defaultValue) {
    x.value = "";
  }
}
function loseFocus() {
  if (x.value == "") {
    x.value = x.defaultValue;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
        <input name="myInput" value="Hello world!" onfocus="getFocus();" onblur="loseFocus();"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="displayResult();" value="Display input value">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with it and how can I define a global variable to be used by all the functions?

Comment: Define doesn't work. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable x is assigned the `document.myForm.myInput` value before the DOM is ready.
You could place the script after your form and myInput elements have been declared, set the script to run in the onload event, or use jQuery's on document ready support (other js libraries offering similar support are available).

Option 1:

```
<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput"> ...
  </form>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
</body>
```

Option 2:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var x = document.myForm.myInput;
  ...
};
```

Option 3:

```
(function($) {
   $(function() {
     var x = document.myForm.myInput;
     ...
   });
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: More specifically, before the HTML parser has parsed the `<form>` element. The script needs to be placed after the `<form>` element

Comment: @rich.okelly: Thanks for the answer and clarification! I just wonder how you compare the first and second option.

Comment: how is the third option executing the code before the dom is ready? It's just a self-invoking anonymous function that executes when it's being parsed.

Comment: @RainLover Personally. I prefer having the scripts at the end of a page, I *try* to adhere to progressive enhancement principals, so the page will still be functional while the user is waiting for the script to load.

Comment: @gion_13 The third option registers a handler to the jQuery DOM ready event when the self-invoking function is parsed, however the code within the inner function only executes as a result of that event (after the DOM is ready).

Answer (score 8):

To make a variable visible in all scopes, you should declare it in the most global scope :

```
<script>
    var variableName;
</script>
```

or you could pin it to the global context (window) :

```
window['variableName'] = value;
```

Your code doesn't work because of the fact that when x is being defined, the form is not available, which means that you assign nothing to the variable.
You should wrap your initialization in an event handler for the onload event:

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.x = document.myForm.myInput;
};
```

or

```
var x;
window.onload = function(){
    x = document.myForm.myInput;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code runs before the rest of the document is loaded. Try placing it at the end, or consider using the `onLoad` event of `body`, or if you want to use a library such as jQuery, you could use the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the whole `<script>` content in a load or domready event, it should work. Alternativly you could put the whole `<script>`-tag at the bottom of the website (right before closing `</body>`- tag